# C# Method argument of Type IRepository<BaseType> doesnt accept implementation inheriting from BaseType

Tags: c#, generics, repository, ninject

I have a generic service that performs the same actions against any given request/response combination. The only time anything specific happens is when it comes to persistence. I'm trying to inject a specific implementation of an repository based off one of the Types (TRequest) in use. So far I have the below, but Ninject and integration tests failing to find any repository that matches what its looking for, a Repository of Type EntityBase. I thought it would be fine as my specific entities inherit from EntityBase...

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Repositories.IRepository<Models.PersonModel>' to 'Repositories.IRepository<Models.EntityBase>'

***EDIT: I know why im getting the current error, its pretty explicit. Any ideas how I can achieve this?***

**PersonModel.cs**

```
public class PersonModel : EntityBase
{
    blah blah
}
```

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<T> 
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

**PersonRepository.cs**

```
public class PersonRepository : IRepository<PersonModel> 
{
    blah blah
}
```

**Service.cs**

```
public class Service<TRequest, TResponse> : IService<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRepository<EntityBase> _repository;

    public Service(IRepository<EntityBase> repository)
    {
        _respository = repository
    }

    public TResponse Call(TRequest request)
    {
        var requestEntity = MapperFactory.GetMapperFor(typeof(TRequest)).Map(request); 

        _repository.Add(requestEntity)

        blah blah blah return            
    }
}
```

**IoCModule.cs**

```
Bind<IRepository<PersonModel>>().To<PersonRepository>();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code (Ninject) fully, but perhaps your IoC module should `Bind<IRepository<EntityBase>>().To<PersonRepository>();`. I'm not sure how the `To<T>()` part determines how to create the class instance. Just trying to help. Or that will just shift the issue to a different location

Comment: If `TRequest` inherits from `EntityBase` you can change to `IRepository<TRequest>`

Comment: I agree with @ArturoMenchaca. Based on the `Call(TRequest request)` in the service, The repository should be `IRepository<TRequest>`.

Comment: Sorry i'll edit the example, its mapped to to a requestDTO, which Inherits from EentityBase

Comment: Hi Tom, you should definately read about [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn why it is impossible to achieve what you want to.

Comment: @Steven yee have done as per a deleted answers suggestion. Changed tack and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because even though PersonModel inherits from EntityBase, this does not mean that `IRepository<PersonModel>` inherits from `IRepository<EntityBase>`.

One possible way to deal with this is to have a third generic type:

```
public class Service<TRequest, TResponse, T> : IService<TRequest, TResponse, T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
}
```

Or another way is to specify the type of the service:

```
public class PersonService<TRequest, TResponse> : IService<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRepository<PersonModel> _repository;
}
```

Comment: I'll rephrase my question, i'm asking for way to achieve what i'm outlining i guess. But thanks.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give the specific service a go.

Answer (score 1):

Because your IRepository< T > uses T as a parameter (input), you cannot make IRepository< T> covariant which would thus allow assigning IRepository< PersonModel> to IRepository< EntityBase>.  So IoC cannot work here.

You will need to write unit tests specific to each implementation for IRepository< T>, as opposed to relying on a generic test for IRepository< EntityBase>.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Repositories.IRepository<Models.PersonModel>` and `Repositories.IRepository<Models.EntityBase>` are effectively different types.

Comment: Yee i get that, guess im asking for ideas on how i can achieve this.